# Are there tools like boosts bcp for Eigen?

Tags: c++, boost, eigen, eigen3

in a project I use a very small portion of Eigen. I want to offer the user of my code two options:

1. download eigen and link to it
2. use built-in eigen shipped with my code

For option 2) I do not want to ship the whole of Eigen, but only the subpart I need. Boost offers for such occasions the tool bcp, that finds all dependencies and separates all the necessary headers. Is there something like this available for Eigen, too? And is this conform with the license?

Comment: Eigen is really really small, so you shouldn't worry about shipping it with the source code, or asking the user to download it

Answer (score 1):

Eigen is a header only library. You should not need to redistribute it; there is nothing to link to.

From their [website](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=FAQ):

> Eigen is only a compile-time dependency for your project. No need to redistribute, or ask your user to install, any library.

If you are distributing source code, I'm not exactly sure how the license applies. You could have your build tool try to locally find Eigen first, then pull the headers from the Eigen repo if it doesn't succeed.

Comment: Pull headers from the Eigen repo is only possible, if internet is available. This is not always the case for my users. Since Eigen is approximately 7MB big, and I need probably only 1MB, I'd like to do without the unused 6MB, because there are some users that say "this lib is bigger, it must be worse"...

Comment: Are you sure that's the size of the headers? There's a lot of other stuff in the repo related to test, etc. You should only need the headers to build against it. Eigen is licensed under MPL. FAQ here: https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/MPL/2.0/FAQ/

Comment: Jep, I installed it and checked just the headers. Well the unsupported part is 1.8MB, but the rest is still pretty big. Thanks for the license link!